# Getting Tweep Error 34 when switching from single user to range

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to scrape last 1-10 tweets from approx 500 user names on twitter.
Code works perfectly when grabbing 1 user, but falls over when introducing a range of users.

First code is single user - Will grab last 7 tweets from Gavinfree and write to CSV

```
import tweepy 
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "secretcode"
consumer_secret = "secretcode"
access_key = "secretcode"
access_secret = "secretcode"


def get_all_tweets(GavinFree):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    alltweets = []
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = GavinFree,count=7)
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = GavinFree,count=7,max_id=10)
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))
    outtweets = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % GavinFree ,'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("GavinFree")
```

Second code is range of users - Will grab 7 tweets from each user and write to CSV and apart from the range - is completely identical.

```
    import tweepy 
    import csv

    #Twitter API credentials
    consumer_key = "secretcode"
    consumer_secret = "secretcode"
    access_key = "secretcode"
    access_secret = "secretcode"

handles_list = ["gavinFree","bdunkelman","burnie","ashleyj",]

def get_all_tweets(handles_list):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    alltweets = []
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = handles_list,count=10)
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = handles_list,count=10,max_id=10)
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % handles_list, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("handles_list")
```

The Error code i receive is *tweepy.error.TweepError: [(u'message' : u'sorry, that page does not exist.' , u'code :34)]*

I have checked out the user names and have tried both *with* @ and *without*. 
I'm just wondering what the issue could be, as code 34 indicates a 404 error on the twitter api page, yet the error is only being introduced when the range is added.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont think `user_timeline` accept a list, you need a loop

Comment: could you try a loop in your `if __name__ == '__main__'` and if encounter any error, just edit your question

Comment: @pedro von hertwig's answer worked perfectly.

Comment: glad you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing handles_list as a string literal, and the function doesn't seem modified to handle a list.

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for handle in handles_list:
        get_all_tweets(handle)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you !